# HERE Android SDK (PREMIUM EDITION) Error: MISSING_LIBRARIES : Native libraries missing: MAPSJNI

Tags: android, react-native, here-api

When install and start app-arm64-v8a-release.apk on real device, get an alert message:

Error: MISSING_LIBRARIES
Native libraries missing: MAPSJNI

[Native libraries missing: MAPSJNI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3f8Uy.jpg)

1. I created a new React Native project and integrated HERE Android SDK (PREMIUM EDITION) version 3.16 into it.:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.2"
  },
```

Then I added these config into build.gradle to build 2 apk files:

```
    splits {
       abi {
           enable true
           reset()
           include 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
           exclude 'x86', 'x86_64'
           universalApk false
       }
   }
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
        exclude 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
        exclude 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
    }
```

```
  app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk (32 bit)
  app-arm64-v8a-release.apk (64 bit)
```

The app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk works well, but the app-arm64-v8a-release.apk got an issue:

[Native libraries missing: MAPSJNI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3f8Uy.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for raising this issue. we are checking this with our engineering team. will update you shortly over the same.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the library, that is used in the project, breaks loading libc++*shared.so.
we set the libc++* shared.so loading before the SoLoader initialisation and the crashes stopped.
Just put System.loadLibrary("c++_shared"); before SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false); in the method MainApplication.onCreate
Please check the workaround.

Comment: I have followed your guidance and modified `MainApplication.java` `onCreate()` function.
Then I built 2 APKs and got the same result:
The app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk works well, but the app-arm64-v8a-release.apk got the same issue.

I was confused that why 32-bit works well but 64-bit does not, they was built from the same source code.

Looking forward to your response, thanks a lot.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share some sample code on the git repo, so that we can share this to our engineering team and then they could replicate, suggest

Comment: I have created a test project on github: [TestHereMapOnRN](https://github.com/wangxinxuan/TestHereMapOnRN), check into it please. Many thanks!

Comment: Hey there, is there any update? Do you need me to provide more info?

Comment: This is strange, we can't reproduce issue. We are able to create the provided app TestHereMapOnRN and both APKs work without issues. Please can you kindly share the detail steps how to replicate the issue. It would be also useful if you share which device are you using for testing.

Comment: Could you please provide the 32-bit and 64-bit APKs that you've built on your environment to me for testing?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve this issue by adding

```
implementation(name: 'HERE-sdk', ext: 'aar')
```

**first** in my dependencies block, rather than in the middle or something.

So my app's build.gradle looks like:

```
...
dependencies {

    implementation(name: 'HERE-sdk', ext: 'aar')

    // Here on downwards are the rest of my dependencies..
    // eg: 
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0-alpha02'
    // and so on ...
```

Answer (score 0):

What device did you use? If you used an emulator with a 32-bit image, then Android will definitely not load a 64-bit .so. Also, the same effect is possible on older devices with a 32-bit processor.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add this in app/build.gradle

```
android {
 ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion
}
```

and in build in the main directory

```
ext {
 ndkVersion = "22.1.7171670"
}
```

I try this and now I can see the map in arm64-v8a architectures :)

Note: If you have jniLibs custom installed please remove